# fetching huge resultset in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc, sqlexception

I am trying to fetch huge set of results from db. I am getting the below Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: statement handle not executed
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doDescribe(T4CStatement.java:724)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1914)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:1515)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
```

I am using the following query and processing like below:

```
rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);

        while (rs.next()) {
            info = new IntoTClass();
            info.setId(rs.getString("column1"));
            info.setContentId(rs.getString("column1"));
            info.setAssetId(rs.getString("column2"));

            info.setKeywords(rs.getString("column3"));
            info.setAssetType(rs.getString("column4"));
            info.setSubType(rs.getString("column5"));
```

I believe the error is because of the huge result its trying to get from the DB. Can anyone suggest how to split the results from the resultset and process like 3000 at a time? ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: How huge is it? Several millions of records is OK for JDBC

Comment: *I believe the error is because of the huge result its trying to get from the DB* guess again. "statement handle not executed" means it didn't run the query.

Comment: Its not millions but just about 20k results.@Ivan. Do you see why the Exhausted ResultSet error is coming up for any other reason?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am sorry i didnt get you. You mean the query itself didnt run?

Comment: Correct. The query itself has not been executed. The error says you tried to get the results, but there isn't any active query to get the results from.

Comment: What oracle driver and what is the precise oracle error code?

Answer (score 0):

Source : https://jazz.net/forum/questions/210782/list-rqm-reports-fails-with-the-statement-handle-not-executed

This issue can be related to JDBC driver.You have to use the version According to system requirements we require using Oracle Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) ojdbc6.jar.11.2.0.3 or higher. Change driver version to check whether the issue is fixed.